# Is there a way to add a column with file permissions (rwx) in Mac OS X's Finder?

Tags: macos, permissions

I like using ls -l but it would be convenient to have this information shown in the Finder. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

That is not one of the columns supported by the Finder's list view.  [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/), a Finder replacement application, will show this information in a column in its list view.

[image: Path Finder list view]

Answer (score 2):

A solution for your problem would be using the Inspector.

When using Finder, type `Cmd+Opt+I`.

It's like having the "Show Information" window, except it shows the information for the selected folder.