# Display permissions in Finder?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, permissions, finder

Is there a way (or plugin) to display permissions in Snow Leopard's Finder? Something like the CLI would be useful, e.g.

```
drwx------
```

Comment: To add a column to the finder see this SU entry: http://superuser.com/questions/28382/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-column-with-file-permissions-rwx-in-mac-os-xs-finder

Answer (score 0):

Right click in your file and choose 'get info'.  At the bottom of the window there will be a tab called 'sharing & permissions'. It lists the users and their permissions.  Otherwise I do not know of any other way to edit your permissions using the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to display them in finder, in a list view. I don't actually need to edit them.